# Dropdown lists in IE are interfering with CSS hover styles

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a webpage that's using a pure CSS menu system. The menu expands when the user moves the mouse over it and collapses when the mouse leaves. The problem is I have a HTML dropdown list inside this menu - that is, a "select" element, and in Internet Explorer, moving the mouse over any items in the "select" is causing the menu to collapse.

My tests indicate that in IE versions including 11, moving the mouse over "option" items in a "select" list causes the parent element of the "select" to no longer be regarded as :hover.

This JS fiddle illustrates the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/q3L2m3ys/

When I run this fiddle in Opera 27.0, the box turns green when the mouse is over it, and it stays green even after clicking the "select" element and moving the mouse over an item in the list. So my CSS menus should work fine in Opera.

However in IE 11, the box turns red again once you click on the  and move the mouse over "option" elements in the list.

How can I get "select" elements in IE to behave themselves and "pass through" the :hover state to the underlying element like they do in Opera? Note: I've already tried pointer-events:none; and it didn't work.

```
  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/q3L2m3ys/

.TestCss{
    width:300px; height:300px;
    background-color:red;
}

.TestCss:hover {
    background-color:green;
}

<div class="TestCss">
    <select name="MyDropDown">
        <option value="1">Test 1</option>
        <option value="2">Test 2</option>
        <option value="3">Test 3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you limited to a CSS only answer or would you try JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: I'm using a prebuilt solution (ACE responsive admin template), and their mouseover menus are pure CSS. However I can modify them to use jQuery if I really have to

Comment: So... this is an extremely interesting problem. I have noted that on Chrome, there is no dropdown animation but on IE 11 there is one... which makes me wonder if that simple animation is actually stopping the propagation of the hover event that is put on the parent div... I'm sure there is somebody who can actually better explain this but if you do not figure it out then you can always use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

That saved me (reseting background even if it already set in css file): $('select').css('background-color','red')